# google api can't be contacted from archlinux server

Tags: python, networking, oauth-2.0, archlinux, python-social-auth

I'm running python-social-auth, on a arch virtual server, to get the oauth2 functionality in my app.

When I try to login using google, I get redirected (after i filled in the form) here:

```
/complete/google-oauth2/
```

And then the connection times out.

```
504 Gateway Time-out
```

I tried to see if the server can connect to google's api. I thnk it can't:

```
wget https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

--2014-07-10 15:20:59--  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

Resolving accounts.google.com (accounts.google.com)... xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx::xx, xx.xxx.xxx.xx

Connecting to accounts.google.com (accounts.google.com)|xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx::xx|:xxx... failed: Connection timed out.

Connecting to accounts.google.com (accounts.google.com)|xx.xxx.xxx.xx|:xxx... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 405 Method Not Allowed
2014-07-10 15:23:06 ERROR 405: Method Not Allowed
```

I'm not sure what this means exactly. But I;m guessing that my network isnt allowing me to call that url.

The time on my server was first the default, and then i switched it to the one you see there which is the one in my home.

I just want to say that doing the same wget from my home produces the 405 ERROR, but not the time out error. So i think there's something wrong with the network.

If anyone could help, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An empty GET request to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token shouldn't return anything useful. You need to pass it the scope, redirect URL, client ID, etc.

I can't explain the timeout, though.

Comment: you mean for the wget? yes its true. i just did it to see if the server will respond. and what i saw is that it timedout first. 
also, i can run this exact same config from home.